# how can I change a tsconfig property for a specific folder in my application?

Tags: reactjs, directory, tsconfig, strict

This is the structure of my project

```
app/
   |--src/
         |--folder
   |--tsconfig.json
```

here is my tsconfig file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

*so I want to make the strict property true for the whole app except for that folder*

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot apply one or more ts config properties to a particular directory or any ts file.

Ts config will applied to all the files that you have mentioned in the `"include"` property.

Comment: well should I create a new tsconfig file for that specific folder or just exclude it

Comment: You can do it by creating another tsconfig file. I'll update the answer